# Insert header in a new word document PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I trying to add a header with an image in a new Word document and nothing happens. The Word document is created but the header with the image does not show.  Here is the code

```
$script:word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.application" 
$script:word.visible = $true       
$script:doc = $script:word.Documents.Add()  
$section = $script:doc.Sections(1)
$Header=$Section.Headers.Item(
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdHeaderFooterIndex]::wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
$Header.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\BestPracticesSQLServer\output\LPTBR- 
3H70QW3\image.jpg")
$script:doc.Activate()
```

Can you help me guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extra line should fix it - to have different first page headers/footers in this section, try

```
$Section.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1
```

or to apply that to all sections, try:

```
$script:doc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1
```

What's happening at the moment is that you are correctly inserting the image into a First Page Header, but the first page is actually displaying the "Primary" header, so the image doesn't show up.

NB, I am assuming that on your configuration,

```
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdHeaderFooterIndex]::wdHeaderFooterFirstPage
```

is returning the correct value for `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage` , i.e. `2` . (It doesn't resolve on my system configuration, so I replaced it by `2`)